# WCF Service - Return Class Object With Class Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am creating WCF Web Service

**Below is My Interface**

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "DocumentDispatchPolicyNo", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        List<DispatchDocument> DocumentDispatchPolicyNoPost(string CorrelationID, string PolicyNumber);
```

**My Function in SVC file is**

```
public List<DispatchDocument> DocumentDispatchPolicyNoPost(string CorrelationID, string PolicyNumber)
        {
            List<DispatchDocument> RInfo = new List<DispatchDocument>();
            .....
            return RInfo;
        }
```

**My OutPut is**

{
    "Add": "ASHIRWAD-59 4TH FLOOR, FLAT 4-B TC ROAD, NEW ALI PUR KOLKATA 700053 Pin-WEST BENGA",
    "ChequeAmount": "0.00",
    "ChequeDate": "",
    "ChequeNumber": "",
    "Dept": "POS",
    "DispatchDate": "27-Oct-2016",
    "DispatchID": "2_118629",
    "DispatchMode": "I-POST",
    "DispatchStatus": "SENT",
    "DispatchType": "DIRECT TO CUSTOMER",
    "Message": "",
    "PODNumber": "",
    "ReceivedDate": "",
    "Status": "Success",
    "TicketNumber": ""
  }

**But I want output as**

{
**DocumentDispatch**:
[
  {
    'Add': 'ASHIRWAD-59 4TH FLOOR, FLAT 4-B TC ROAD, NEW ALI PUR KOLKATA 700053 Pin-WEST BENGA',
    'ChequeAmount': '0.00',
    'ChequeDate': '',
    'ChequeNumber': '',
    'Dept': 'POS',
    'DispatchDate': '27-Oct-2016',
    'DispatchID': '2_118629',
    'DispatchMode': 'I-POST',
    'DispatchStatus': 'SENT',
    'DispatchType': 'DIRECT TO CUSTOMER',
    'Message': '',
    'PODNumber': '',
    'ReceivedDate': '',
    'Status': 'Success',
    'TicketNumber': ''
  }]
}

Answer (score 1):

Create the following class

```
  public class DocumentDispatchObject
  {
    public List<DispatchDocument> DocumentDispatch
  }
```

Use the above class like this

```
   public DocumentDispatchObject DocumentDispatchPolicyNoPost(string CorrelationID, string PolicyNumber)
    {
       DocumentDispatchObject RInfo = new DocumentDispatchObject();
        .....
        return RInfo;
    }
```